# How do I include all records 5 Days after date index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a data table, let's call it `dt` and a date index table, let's call it `dt_idx`. I would like to get:

1. all records from dt where dt.date = dt_idx.date AND
2. all records from dt where dt.date is 1-5 days later from every dt_idx.date. (NOTE: DO NOT ASSUME dt.date IS CONSECUTIVE, dates could be missing)

Here is a sql fiddle: [Click Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5233b/2)

Here is a sample schema:

```
CREATE TABLE dt_idx
(
  d DATE,
  v INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO dt_idx (d, v)
SELECT '2019-02-10', CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000 as INT) + 1
UNION
SELECT '2019-03-05', CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000 as INT) + 1


CREATE TABLE dt
(
  d DATE,
  a int,
  b int
)

declare @sdate date = '2019-01-01'
    , @edate date = '2019-03-24'

; with dates_CTE (date) as (
        select @sdate 
    Union ALL
        select DATEADD(day, 1, date)
        from dates_CTE
        where date < @edate
) select *
into #temp
from dates_CTE 

INSERT INTO dt(d, a, b)
SELECT date, CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000 as INT) + 1, CAST(RAND(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) * 1000 as INT) + 1
from #temp
```

Here is the output I am expecting (columns a & b would be some random numbers as per the table):

```
d           |    a  |   b
2019-02-10     123     123
2019-02-11     234     344
2019-02-12     234     344
2019-02-13     234     344
2019-02-14     234     344
2019-03-05     234     344
2019-03-06     234     344
2019-03-07     234     344
2019-03-08     234     344
2019-03-09     234     344
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results *in the question* as *text tables* would really help.  This condition in particular does not make sense:  "all records from dt where dt.date is 1-5 days later from every dt_idx.date."

Comment: What's your question here? You've provided your attempt(s?) but not stated if anything is wrong with them. (Only thing I can see "wrong" with it is the design choice of using an rCTE instead of a Tally.)

Comment: added the output I would expect

Comment: Your naming conventions here are, I think, taking what could be a well presented question and making it unnecessarily confusing. Naming your table `dt`, which is a fairly universal abbreviation for `date`, for instance, makes the problem statement very difficult to read. The single letter, meaningless column names aren't doing you or us any favors, either.

Comment: @EricBrandt thank you for the advice. Will keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You question is a bit hard to follow.  I think you want all records from `dt` that are zero to five days later than records in `dt_idx`.

If so, you can use `exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM dt
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM dt_idx di
              WHERE dt.d >= di.d AND
                    dt.d < DATEADD(day, 5, di.d)
             );
```

Comment: You nailed it! Exactly what I was looking for!